# How to bypass varnish cache based on specific header

Tags: varnish, varnishncsa

I've been working on this since 2 days ago, but no luck.

So, basically, I want to bypass the varnish cache for a specific incoming request URL.

I've defined this rule:

```
sub vcl_recv {
     if (req.url ~ "/en/reading-books/") { return(pass); }
}
```

But when I refresh the page, it's still being cached, the response headers return these:

```
via: 1.1 varnish-v4
x-varnish: 2
```

and this background-running command produces output:

```
varnishncsa -F '%{Host}i %h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-agent}i"'
```

What am I missing here? Any pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: what version of varnish are you running? This should work fine in varnish 6 atleast. Could you post a obfuscated but complete config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Upgrade to a supported version

Before I talk about debugging caching of that incoming URL, I want to point out that **you're running an end-of-life version of Varnish that has known security vulnerabilities**.

Please either upgrade to the latest version or use Varnish Cache 6.0 LTS.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/#installations for a list of install guides for a variety of Linux distributions.

### Matching an exact URL or a URL pattern

The VCL code you shared bypasses the cache for `/en/reading-books`. Are you trying to do an exact match on that URL or a pattern that matches a set of URLs?

For an exact match, I'd adjust the URL as follows:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url == "/en/reading-books/") { 
        return(pass); 
    }

}
```

When you're matching multiple URLs, all of which start with `/en/reading-books/`, I'd adjust the VCL as follows:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url == "^/en/reading-books/.*$") { 
        return(pass); 
    }

}
```

### What about the Varnish-specific response headers

You mentioned the following headers in your question:

```
via: 1.1 varnish-v4
x-varnish: 2
```

These indicate that you're using Varnish, not necessarily that Varnish serves the response from the cache.

The `via` header just informs the user about the fact that Varnish is a proxy server in the response chain.

The value of the `x-varnish` header usually refers to the ID of the transaction that handled your request.

It's actually the `Age` header that indicates how long a response has been served from cache for.

### Checking the logs

The `varnishncsa` command has access to the Varnish Shared Memory Logs, but doesn't really display a lot of useful caching information.

The purpose of `varnishncsa` is the return access log information, similar to what Apache & Nginx return.

Please run the following command to debug the caching:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/en/reading-books/.*$'"
```

While `varnishncsa` produces an NCSA-format single-line response, `varnishlog` will return the full transaction. Please add the output from `varnishlog` to your question and I'll help you debug.

Comment: This is a pretty clear explanation, especially that regex pattern, it gives me a better understanding of how to process similar incoming requests. You just saved my day, thank you!

Comment: btw, I've upgraded to version 6 as you suggested, it works better now.